# Creating a wrapper for a C library in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to create a wrapper of my own for FLAC, so that I can use FLAC in my own Python code.

I tried using ctypes first, but it showed a really weird interface to the library, e.g. all the init functions for FLAC streams and files became one function with no real information on how to initialize it. Especially since it wants a reference to a stream decoder, but Python has no way to store pointers ( [BZZZT!](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) ), and thus I can't store the pointer to the stream decoder. It doesn't help that the different init functions have a different number of arguments and some argument types differ. It also has a lot of enumerations and structures, and I don't know how to get these into my code.

I've been looking into Pyrex, but I kinda ran into the same problem with pointers, but I think I solved it, sort-of. [The file isn't small either, and it's not even complete.](http://github.com/Bocom/zet-subou-/blob/db6d1d37068c936f1e3a98b09ec038b38b7d25e0/flac_wrapper.pyx)

So I'm looking for alternatives, or guides that would help me understand the aforementioned ways better. It would really help if I could get a recommendation and/or help.

Answer (score 11):

> Python has no way to store pointers, and thus I can't store the pointer to the stream decoder

**ctypes** has pointers, and ctypes can be used to wrap existing C libraries. Just a tip, you will need to wrap/rewrite all relavent C structures into ctypes.Structure. 
 Take look at examples: [code.google.com/p/pyxlib-ctypes](http://code.google.com/p/pyxlib-ctypes/) and [code.google.com/p/pycairo-ctypes](http://code.google.com/p/pyxlib-ctypes/). More info how to map function/procedure and its *argtypes* and *restype* at http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

> I've been looking into Pyrex, but I kinda ran into the same problem with pointers, but I think I solved it, sort-of. The file isn't small either, and it's not even complete.

**cython** may be what you need if you want clean syntax. [www.cython.org](http://www.cython.org)

> So I'm looking for alternatives, or guides that would help me understand the aforementioned ways better. It would really help if I could get a recommendation and/or help.

**swig** on other hand can always be used but it is more complicated if you are not used to it. [www.swig.org](http://www.swig.org)

Answer (score 5):

Did you have a look at http://www.swig.org/:

> SWIG is a software development tool
>   that connects programs written in C
>   and C++ with a variety of high-level
>   programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

> but Python has no way to store pointers ( BZZZT! )

That is incorrect. You create a pointer like this:

```
pInt = POINTER(c_int)()
```

and you access it like this

```
pInt[0] # or p.contents
```

Answer (score 3):

This post is old, but there's an alternative to `ctypes`: [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org). It's a lot easier, somewhat faster, and works better under PyPy. Plus, it has great support for pointers. Here's an example:

```
from cffi import FFI

ffi = cffi.FFI()

ffi.cdef('''
struct x { void *a; }

void* get_buffer();
struct x* make_x(void*);
void change_x(struct x*, void*);
''')

dll = ffi.dlopen('libmyawesomelibrary.so')

buf = dll.get_buffer()
tst = dll.new('struct x*')
tst.a = buf
change_x(tst, get_buffer())
tst2 = make_x(get_buffer())
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people use [pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) for this.

Comment: Cython is based on the well-known Pyrex, but supports more cutting edge functionality and optimizations.