# Assign to variable exported from shared library via Python CTypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a shared lib `libtest.so` made from `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int value;
void fn() { printf("%d\n", value); }
```

Now I'm wrapping this library from Python using CTypes. I know that I can *read* `value` from Python as follows:

```
In[2]: c_int.in_dll(lib, "value")
Out[2]: c_int(0)
```

(I learnt the above from [Mapping a global variable from a shared library with ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544173/mapping-a-global-variable-from-a-shared-library-with-ctypes).)

However, if I try to *write* to the same, then it complains:

```
In[3]: c_int.in_dll(lib, "value") = 2
  File "<ipython-input-4-5a1e8ea6a1b4>", line 1
    c_int.in_dll(lib, "value") = 2
                                  ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Presumably this is because the c_int object doesn't directly "point" to the C memory location.

Of course, I can write and export a `setValue` function that can receive data from Python to modify `value` from within C, but I am wondering whether there is any way to do *without* that.

[Assigning Python function to ctypes pointer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160077/assigning-python-function-to-ctypes-pointer-variable) seems to indicate this is not possible, but would like a specific answer hence posting the specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `c_int` *does* point at the `value` of `test.c`. You will want to write to the `value`attribute of the `c_int` to write to the underlying memory that the `c_int` wraps. Otherwise you would simply be replacing one Python object with another in Python-land and not having any effect in C land. For example:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> i = ctypes.c_int()
>>> i
c_int(0)
>>> i.value = 10
>>> i
c_int(10)
```

## Proof of Concept

Below, I'll give the C file, how the C file should be compiled, and the python code to show that the above works. This is specifically for a Unix-like environment (including WSL). If you're using Windows directly, then  compilation instructions and how to load the library will differ.

#### mylib.c

```c
int value = 10;

int
get_value() {
        return value;
}
```

#### Compilation Instructions

```bash
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC -c mylib.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC -shared -o mylib.so mylib.o
```

#### main.py

```py
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')

get_value = mylib.get_value
get_value.argtypes = []
get_value.returntype = int


library_value = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(mylib, 'value')

initial_value = get_value()

print(f'{initial_value=}')
print(f'{library_value=}')
print()

library_value.value = 123
assigned_value = get_value()

print(f'{initial_value=}')
print(f'{assigned_value=}')
print(f'{library_value=}')
```

#### output

```
initial_value=10
library_value=c_int(10)

initial_value=10
assigned_value=123
library_value=c_int(123)
```

Comment: This corrects his SyntaxError, but it doesn't answer the main question of how to write to a variable in a shared object library from python. I tried ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lib, "value").value = 2 but it doesn't change the value.

Comment: This solution works fine for me. You'd be best off posting a new question with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue you are having. I'll update the answer with the proof-of-concept code, in case that helps.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. I may have been using the wrong type, e.g. writing to a uint8 instead of uint32 or vice versa.